$\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A} \cup N_{\mu}$.
Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space,
Let $N_{\mu} = \{B \subset X :
\text{ there is }  C \in \mathcal{A} \text{ such that } B \subset C \text{ and } \mu[C] = 0\}$ and $\mathcal{\bar{A}}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A} \cup N_{\mu}$.
Let
$\mathcal{A}_{1} = \{A \cup B : A \in \mathcal{A} \text{  and }  B \in N_{\mu} \}$
$\mathcal{A}_{2} = \{A∆B : A \in \mathcal{A} \text{ and } B \in N_{\mu}\}$
$\mathcal{A}_{3} = \{A - B : A \in \mathcal{A} \text{ and } B \in N_{\mu} \}$
$\mathcal{A}_{4} = \{(A \cup B_{1})-B_{2} : A \in \mathcal{A} \text{ and } B_{1}, B_{2} \in N_{\mu} \}$
Show that $\mathcal{A}_{i} = \mathcal{\bar{A}}$ for $1 \leq i \leq 4$ and $\mu$ has a natural extension $\bar{\mu }$ to $\mathcal{\bar{A}}.$
At first, I showed that $\mathcal{A}_{1}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathcal{A}_{1}=\mathcal{\bar{A}}$, after that $\mathcal{A}_{1} = \mathcal{A}_{2}$.
I am stuck at proving the remaining equality, $\mathcal{A}_{2}=\mathcal{A}_{3}=\mathcal{A}_{4}$.
For $\mathcal{A}_{2}=\mathcal{A}_{3}$, I tried to express $A \cup B$ in terms of $E-F$ for some $E \in \mathcal{A}$ and $F \in N_{\mu}$ so that $\mathcal{A}_{1} \subset \mathcal{A}_{3}$ and the other inclusion follows from $\mathcal{A}_{1}$ being a $\sigma$-algebra. How can I do that?
Thank you.

I would try to show that $\mathcal A_1 = \mathcal A_3$. (Think about taking complements...)
